# after deploy the site need exact domain name with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am going to deploy my site and I need to get the domain name after deploying the site. 
It is very simple if the address was `www.domain.com` then the domain name is `domain.com`
but if the client deploys the site as a sub domain like `subdomain.domain.com` then how can I get exact domain name? I have  already get host name with

```
window.location.hostname
```

I need exact domain name after deploying the site to set a cookie 
I don't know what domain the client will be use

- option 1 www.domain.com
- option 2 domain.com
- option 3 subdomain.domain.com
- option 4 subdomain.domain.com.us
- option 5 domain.com.us
  etc

What function do I write to apply for all conditions and get exact domain name 
in jQuery?

Comment: i already mentioned i have host name but i need to get domain name for set cookie and need to something like which apply at all conditions  as i mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0):

This should work alright:

```
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var parts = hostname.split('.');
var domain = parts.slice(-2, parts.length).join('.');
```

Comment: Will this work correctly for domains like `mydomain.com.au` and `mydomain.co.uk` ?

Comment: this is not return the correct value for domains as techfoobar mentioned same as if {window.location.hostname;} return www.google.com.uk then this function return only com.uk i think we have to apply many conditions like {if(hostname == subdomain.domain.com) and if(hostname ==  www.domain.com)if(hostname == domain.com.uk) ect}